# What is modifying the "i" in Thumbelina and Carolina to alter its pronuciation?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

While helping my daughter read (she is 5) we encountered two names in a story, Thumbelina and Carolina.  The way I've come to pronounce the last four letters of "Thumbelina" is "LEE NAH" and the same part of "Carolina" as "LIE NAH".  My question is what is modifying the sound "i" makes in each name?  Is there a name for this rule? Am I just pronouncing "Thumbelina" or "Carolina" incorrectly?

Comment: What is modifying the pronunciation of 'sow' (the female pig) to change it to 'sow' (scatter seed)? Not a lot within the structure of the word. Why are the last two syllables of 'Arkansas' normally pronounced differently from 'Kansas'? And I think that (the river) 'Arkansas' is pronounced to rhyme with 'Kansas' in Kansas! You're pronouncing Thumbelina (to rhyme with semolina!) and Carolina (to rhyme with Regina) correctly, but I wouldn't expect someone to come up with a nice neat rule to help with other words with the same ending.

Comment: hat / hate; red / rede; spit / spite; tor / tore;  cut / cute - obviously, the **following** _e_ 'changes' the vowel sound in each of these cases. There are _some_ rules of thumb, but as the above examples show, there are inconsistencies (sadly, many!) Often, the rationale behind these idiosyncrasies is lost in time (or at least, until Jon Hanna comes up with the explanation).

Comment: Hey - the follow-on question that makes sense of the above just disappeared!

Comment: Just look at the history of long vowels in English: in this case, long i. It has two variants in ModE: diphthong I; close vowel like in Lee. Same thing applies to long u: diphthong like in cow; and the close vowel like in soup. That's we have variant pronunciations for words like *via* and *router*. In two syllable words, you can see the first vowel as old long vowel due to open syllable lengthening: that's why you hear the first syllable of *Dana* like *day*. And this does not have that silent-e.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, sorry, it seemed like it's own question (and a rather dumb one at that :P, I deleted it)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes, but even my explanation allows for a lot of leeway and unexplained oddities to spoil it, so it doesn't contradict the crux of your comments here.

Comment: I don't understand the _even_, Jon - your explanation was excellent, making a lot of sense (and dispelling a little of my ignorance) (ta!). I was just suggesting that you could be in for rather a lot of work if you're going to treat us to similarly thorough explanations of life, the universe and (especially) the idiosyncrasies of English. Though I wouldn't dream of discouraging you!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth by the "even" I mean that while I could provide an answer to this particular question, it still contains a degree of conjecture because of those idiosyncrasies you'd mentioned, so most of the time I can only speak to likely causes rather than anything definite. It also helps that this was about a H.C. Andersen character, and that I'd previously wondered myself why there is an *o* in the adjective *Caroline* (It's because it's via Latinised *Carolus*). It completely beats me why  *semolina* has the same sound (the Italian is *semola*, where did the *in* come from at all?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Thumbelina* is was coined by H.W. Dulcken in the 19th Century as an Anglicisation of *Tommelise* (itself a 19th Century Danish coinage by Hans Christian Andersen) so it could quite possibly be influenced by the sound of the *I* in that word. It also, being a recent coinage is likely to be strongly influenced just by what people thought sounded better—there was no rule about how to pronounce it until Dulcken's translation came out, so even if he'd said it rhymed with *Carolina* and people thought it sounded better as is, it would have changed (unless he'd actually written his translation as a rhyming poem, but he didn't).

*Carolina* - both the states' and girls' name - comes from the Latin form of *Charles* and are related to the word *Caroline* as a girls' name, and *Caroline* as a separate but related adjective form of *Charles* (hence the adjective *Caroline* for things relating the the reign of a King Charles).

When adjective forms produced from other words end in *-ine* we tend to pronounced them with /aɪn/ sounds, and so we would expect a related *-ina* to be more likely to end up with a /aɪnɑ/ or maybe /aɪnæ/, but we'd be surprised if they ended up /iːnə/. Not very surprised, because it's not like this stuff is always logical, but a bit.

Ironically, in Thumbelina's native language of Danish, Karoline (a common Danish form of Carolina), is pronounced /kɐroˈli·nə/ (say "caroleena" but swallow the R so it's almost "caowleena"—think of the lack of R sound on the end of words ending in R in some English accents) and does come close to rhyming with Thumbelina, but not with Tommelise.

5 Year Old Version:

Normally it's I-NAH, but sometimes it isn't. Thumbelina was first called Tommelise TOM-Eh-LEES-AH, because she's from another country, the same one that the little mermaid is from and where her statue is, and names are the hardest to spell because a lot are from languages other than English, so they work differently. Semolina is funny too, because semolina is just funny.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a rich answer, now I have to try and keep this to myself so as not to discourage my daughter from working on sounding out words :)